# Is "this is the man who stolen my car" grammatically correct?

Tags: tense, relative-pronouns, contractions

I had this in my last english exam and I had a to choose between 4 answers
"this is the man (who-whose-who's-which) stolen my car"
"who" is the only answer which makes sense to me although  I think the whole question is grammerlicaly incorrect

Comment: Related question:  [This is gotta be the worst job in the world](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51814)

Comment: The answers that say "who's" is grammatically correct are right, but your unease is understandable — the phrasing of the statement is atypical, and you'd be more likely to hear "the man who stole my car." "The person who has stolen [something]" feels very stilted and formal, and replacing "who has" with its contraction only compounds the awkwardness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"who's" is "who has" which would make the sentence grammatically correct.

Comment: but i heard that who's is same as "who is"

Comment: +1.  This is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @AmirWG An *'s* is a contraction of both *is* and *has* (as well as the regular way to indicate a possessive), and which meaning is intended would be inferred from context. Similarly, *'d* may represent either *had* or *would*.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be who's = "who has".

"He stolen my car" is incorrect. "He stole" or "he has stolen".

Comment: so you are saying that the question was wrongly  composed at first place?

Comment: @AmirWG "Who's" is a contraction. It can stand for **either** "who is" **or** "who has". In this case "who has" makes this sentence grammatically right.